# How to add objects to existing properties with Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to declare a variable named `newRobot`. `newRobot` should be a new object that has all the properties of `robot` and the properties in the following object: `{laserBlaster: true, voiceRecognition: true}`. It should be done with the help of `Object.asign()`. I don't want to change the `robot` object.

It's about the code after the last comment.
Here is the code so far:

```
const robot = {
    model: 'SAL-1000',
  mobile: true,
  sentient: false,
  armor: 'Steel-plated',
  energyLevel: 75
};

// What is missing in the following method call?
const robotKeys = Object.keys(robot);

console.log(robotKeys);

// Declare robotEntries below this line:
const robotEntries = Object.entries(robot);

console.log(robotEntries);

// Declare newRobot below this line:
const newRobot = Object.assign(robot, {laserBlaster: true, voiceRecognition: true})

console.log(newRobot);
```

Comment: I am sorry. I just saw that this question seemed to be a duplicate! I am new and learning how to code. Next time I will take more care before asking a question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument passed to `Object.assign` is the concrete object instance that is going to be modified.

So to create a new object, you neet to target an **empty object** `{}` as first parameter of [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
const
    newRobot = Object.assign({}, robot, { laserBlaster: true, voice: true });
    //                       ^^
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use `Object.assign` without change the first object you can do this

`Object.assign` merge all properties from right to left changing the first object

```js
const robot = {
    model: 'SAL-1000',
  mobile: true,
  sentient: false,
  armor: 'Steel-plated',
  energyLevel: 75
};

const newProperties = {laserBlaster: true, voiceRecognition: true}
// Declare newRobot below this line:
const newRobot = Object.assign({},robot, newProperties)

//or

const otherRobot = {...robot, ...newProperties}

console.log({robot, newRobot, otherRobot});
```